# DocuSign Connect -fields

Tags: docusignapi

This is a question about DocuSign Connect.
For certain document types, we have the user upload their docs which have matching templates. We also have them use the 'use a template' where they fill it in online before sending the envelope off.

We can see the fields and values in the XML document and from there we do further processing for the documents.  Lately we have some users that want to upload a large PDF document that doesn't have those fields defined.

Is there a way to set field values on a PDF or Word document that I would be able to use in the XML created for the envelope without users having to fill n a template?

I've tried adding various fields with labels, textboxes to Word documents and PDFs, but I'm not seeing them when debugging the DocuSign connect program. I only see the fields that are defined in the template and the online template users fill in while in DocuSign (the sender fills in the fields before sending off)..

Answer (score 0):

The fields (tabs) have to either:

1. Be defined on the template or envelope somehow, can be using the API or can be using the web app, but they have to be defined. You can use [anchor strings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/) if you don't know how to positions them exactly.
2. use [PDFFormFields transformation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/pdf-transform/) where for PDF documents that are marked with these fields, DocuSign can automatically detect and create the fields (tags).